# Why ferroelectric material needs to be insulating?

Tags: material-science, electronic-band-theory, metals, insulators

Is it necessary for a ferroelectric material to be insulating?
Is it possible for a metal to be ferroelectric?

Answer (score 3):

Ferroelectric materials are polar, meaning that they exhibit a spontaneous dipole moment (i.e. local electric field) within the unit cell. Metals cannot (typically) be polar, as conductive materials do not allow electric fields to exist within the bulk material.

This is because any electric field in the material will immediate cause the electrons to move until the electric field is nullified. In insulators, there are no free charges to cancel out the electric fields, so spontaneous polarization is allowed. In insulating ferroelectric materials, doping can allow for some conductivity, but heavy doping can suppress the ferroelectric polarization.

That being said, polar metals do exist, such as in cuprate semiconductors and some transition metal oxide compounds. So to answer your question: as a rule, ferroelectrics have to be insulating, but exceptions do exist!